# mySQL like, but not like

Tags: mysql, database

I need help with one mysql query. I am unable to find solution for specific like query. I am not even sure, if LIKE operator is what I am looking for.

What I am trying to achive is, finding all rows containig url, if that url is not foo.com

I want this rows:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet example.com consectetuer vitae ut a
>   lobortis metus.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor example.com sit amet consectetuer foo.com vitae ut a
>   lobortis metus.

But I dont want this rows:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer foo.com vitae ut a lobortis
>   metus.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer vitae ut a lobortis
>   metus.

Queries like this wont work..

```
WHERE str like '%.com%'

WHERE (str LIKE '%.com%') && (str NOT LIKE '%foo.com%')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want to fetch only "example.com " String? or other '.com' also but not "foo.com"?

Comment: Replace 'foo.com` to space then like '%.com%'.

Comment: It is sort of blacklist check, if someone is promoting other website in ours PMs. I want to return all rows with url adress, but not those, containging only our url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace 'foo.com` to space then like '%.com%'.

```
REPLACE(str , 'foo.com', ' ') like '%.com%'
```

Comment: This one looks promising, ill give it a try. Thank you